# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 cannot rollback

Tags: database

I have managed to cause this error while working with exposed filters weighting in views.
Any idea how I can correct it? I am running Sqlite for database. Is it possible to clear transactions or something?

Thanks

> Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.
>
> Original
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 cannot rollback - no transaction is active in node_save() (line 1152 of /home/site/public_html/modules/node/node.module).
>
> Additional
>
> PDOException: There is already an active transaction in dblog_watchdog() (line 154 of /home/site/public_html/modules/dblog/dblog.module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with my /tmp directory being full.. Devel module had filled it up.
It's something to be aware of and here is a script to notify you when /tmp is nearing full http://forums.ultratechhost.com/thread-187.html